# Joining Two Tables based upon a Key using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I've got Two tables
Attribute(AID, Name, Description)
AttributeVal(AID,Value)

Now, Using LINQ I need to get the Name, Description and Value by joining these two tables. So, far I got here..

```
        var displayAttributeMap = dctx.Attributes.Join(dctx.AttributeDisplayNames, a => a.AttributeID, adn => adn.AttributeID, 
                                                        (a, adn) => new
                                                        {
                                                            AttributeName = a.Name,
                                                            AttributeDispName = adn.DisplayName
                                                        }
                                                       ).ToDictionary(a => a.AttributeName, a => a.AttributeDispName);
```

But here I don't know where to insert a condition on the foreign key, in my case it is Attribute ID. Am I missing something here or should I use LINQ directly?

Comment: You have joined these two tables on ’AttributeId’ already. What is the problem with your code? Do you want to add ’where’ filter?

Comment: such a confusing code dude ,can you clarify what do you want here ? and make simple join that you understand what do you do in code.

Comment: Sry about the confusion. I am trying to Join Two Tables nased on a Common Key and extract few attributes from these two tables.

Comment: Sry about the confusion. I am trying to Join Two Tables nased on a Common Key and extract few attributes from these two tables. For Eg:- if Table 1 has <10,Value1,Value2> <20,Value2,Value5>,<30,Value6,Value7>. Table 2 Has <20,A>,<30,C> Now I am trying to get <20,Value2,Value5,A> and <30,Value6,Value7>

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you need the value AND the display name of the attribute put into a dictionary.

All you need to do is add another join to your current query and change your select and ToDictionary around a bit. I find using the query syntax easier to read and use when dealing with joins.

```
(from attr in dctx.Attributes
    join attrDisplayName in dctx.AttributeDisplayNames on attr.AttributeID equals attrDisplayName.AttributeID
    join attrVal in dctx.AttributeVal on attr.AttributeID equals attrVal.AttributeID
select new
{
    AttributeName = attr.Name,
    AttributeDispName = attrDisplayName.DisplayName,
    AttributeID = attr.AttributeID,
    AttributeValue = attrVal.Value
}).ToDictionary(key => key.AttributeID, (value) => { return new { DisplayName = value.AttributeDispName, Value = value.AttributeValue };})
```

I haven't tested it but LinqPad is happy with the syntax, so I think it should work.